# Check if datareader is null or has no rows? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I took over this project and one page is throwing a lot of errors. I would need to refactor the whole thing but as always time is an issue.

In one case the code check's whether a datareader has any rows and if not go to an error page. However as the code is now the datareader can be null (didn't successfully connect to db) and in those cases I can't use

```
if (!dr.HasRows)
//
```

becasuse it obviously gives me 'nullreferenceexception was unhandled by code'. I tried with !dr.Read but same thing.

A part of the code is something like

```
SqlDataReader dr = null;
try
{
//connect to db etc
dr = DbHelper.GetReader("sp_GetCustomer", param);
}
catch
{
//show an error message
}

// and then:
if (!dr.HasRows)
{

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about putting the dr.hasrows in the try as well and handle that error as well?

Comment: @Elad: NO!  *Avoid* obvious exceptions, don't catch them.

Comment: @Dan Puzey - Sure, but stuff happens. You can never know, and if the specific stuff happens, I would rather catch it than not... Give some kind of inteligent error.

Comment: @Elad: you can *always* avoid catching `NullReferenceException` by checking the thing you're about to reference.

Comment: @Dan Puzey - Ohh... Now I see what your saying. They your right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about:

```
if (dr == null || !dr.HasRows) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I think that would evaluate !dr.HasRows as well anyway, no?

Comment: of course, I am getting too tired dealing with this mess.  Thanks

Comment: @Elad: No, in C# additional parameters for the `if` statement are only checked as necessary. This is referred to as "short-circuited". You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: If dr==null is true, it will short circuit the evaluation - OR operator has no need to evaluate the right hand side of the expression if it knows the left hand side is true.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is:

```
SqlDataReader dr = null;
try
{
    //connect to db etc
    dr = DbHelper.GetReader("sp_GetCustomer", param);
    if (!dr.HasRows)
    {

    }
}
catch
{
//show an error message
}
```